# Redirecting to paypal checkout from firebase functions doesn' work

Tags: firebase, paypal, cors, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add an option to send a paypal payment.
I used this example:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/paypal

I send the payment request from the client, and when it gets to the line:

```
res.redirect(302, links.approval_url.href)
```

I get this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/...' (redirected from '') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I checked everywhere but couldn't find an answer on how to fix it.
I tried setting the headers, used the cors library but nothing helped (the cors library fixed another error regarding CORS).

I read somewhere that it might no be possible to do it exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) documentation which explains how you should handle those errors. If you continue experiencing the issue, please add a minimum reproducible code sample of the error so that we can provide more help and possibly a code sample of what might work